# Task Manager in C++: HRESULT of E_ACCESSDENIED on task registration

Tags: c++, winapi, com, scheduled-tasks

This is probably a common problem, but I was unable to find it online.
I am attempting to automate managing and creating scheduled tasks on *Windows 10*.

I'm following the [**timed trigger example**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/time-trigger-example--c---) from the Microsoft docs.

I am able to succesfully populate `ITaskDefinition*`, `IRegistrationInfo*`, `IPrincipal*`, `ITaskSettings*`, `ITriggerCollection*`, `IActionCollection*` acccording to that guide (getting S_OK for all), and I'm able to list tasks and delete existing ones. I'm also able to register tasks manually from the GUI.

However, when calling `RegisterTaskDefinition()`, HRESULT becomes `E_ACCESSDENIED`, with no further detail.

This is where I'm configuring the login:

```
void SetPasswordLogin(SchedulerServiceHandle srv, TaskHandle tsk){
    HRESULT auth_s = tsk->principal->put_LogonType(TASK_LOGON_PASSWORD);
    if(FAILED(auth_s)) {
        throw TaskException("Failed to set logon type (password)");
    }
    /*HRESULT user_s = tsk->principal->put_UserId(_wstring2bstring(_domainuser2fqdnuser(srv->auth.domain,srv->auth.user)));
    if(FAILED(user_s)) {
        throw TaskException("Failed to set user");
    }*/
    HRESULT runl_s = tsk->principal->put_RunLevel(TASK_RUNLEVEL_HIGHEST);
    if(FAILED(runl_s)) {
        throw TaskException("Failed to set runlevel");
    }
    tsk->login_type = Task::LoginType::Password;
}
```

And my call to `RegisterTaskDefinition()`:

```
void RegisterTestTask(SchedulerServiceHandle srv,TaskHandle tsk,ITaskFolder* folder,std::wstring name) {
    IRegisteredTask* wintask = nullptr;
    HRESULT wintask_s = folder->RegisterTaskDefinition(
        NULL,//_bstr_t(&name),
        tsk->definition,
        //TASK_VALIDATE_ONLY,
        TASK_CREATE|TASK_UPDATE,
        _wstring2variant(_domainuser2fqdnuser(srv->auth.domain,srv->auth.user)),
        _wstring2variant(srv->auth.pass),
        TASK_LOGON_PASSWORD,
        _variant_t(L""),
        &wintask
    );
    /*snip - error checking*/
}
```

If I run with TASK_VALIDATE_ONLY, it runs without errors.

I've attempted running *Visual Studio* as Administrator figuring it might not have permission, but that changes nothing - same for running the binary directly from an elevated cmd prompt.

I had an older C# version that did work, despite using the same settings and credentials for Principal and Registration, so there must be some extra step I'm missing.

Comment: Additional info: I've tried updating my AD password, as well as tried with a newly created local account, but no luck - the error remains unchanged. It doesn't seem authentication related.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

It turns out that in addition to:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "taskschd.lib")
```

Task scheduler also needs to be linked to comsupp and credui:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "credui.lib")
```

How a lack of linked libraries makes results in E_ACCESSDENIED is baffling me, but I suppose I will learn figure that out once I learn more about the Windows API.